# The use of @property

Tags: ios, objective-c

Why is this code okay?

```
@interface AddViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate>
{


IBOutlet UILabel *category;
IBOutlet UIPickerView *categoryPicker;


}
@end
```

But this code is not

```
@interface AddViewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate>



IBOutlet UILabel *category;
IBOutlet UIPickerView *categoryPicker;



@end
```

Also, I was looking up a video on how to use the UIPickerView, and instead of making properties for the IBOutlet, he just made the outlets. Which clearly has something to do with why those curly braces are there.

Comment: because the second code is a syntax error — that's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`category` and `categoryPicker` are instance variables, not properties. You either reference them directly via their name e.g. `category` or by using `self->category`.

Instance variables are declared in the curly braces, while properties are declared with @property

Instance variables do not have setter and getter methods, while properties have.

Comment: the term "class field" does not make any sense. These do exist in instances, therefor they are called "instance variable" or "ivar"

Comment: why fields? did you do to much html-form coding?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change "IBOutlet UILabel *category;" to "@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UILabel *category;", the same for "IBOutlet UIPickerView *categoryPicker;"

Within the bracket {}, category and categoryPicker are instance variables, but if you delete the "{}", you need to use "property" so that they work the same way